# How can I remove all rows with NaN and retrieve the indicies of the rows I just removed?

Tags: matlab, matrix

Currently, I have an nxm matrix of doubles. Some of the rows in this matrix consist entirely of NaNs. I wish to not only remove these rows from my matrix, but also ultimately have a vector that contains the indexes of the rows I just removed from my matrix. Currently, I have used the statement:

fullData(isnan(fullData(:,1)),:) = []

to remove all my rows with NaNs (with fullData being my nxm matrix). However, I am struggling with the second component, as I need these indices that were just removed. Thanks for any and all help as it is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
myIndices = isnan(fullData(:,1));
fullData(myIndices, :) = [];
```

Now you have the indices that were removed available in `myIndices`. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 2):

use [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html):

```
[row,col] = find(isnan(fullData));
fullData(row,:) = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative that's safer to use in a loop:

```
fullData = fullData(~isnan(fullData(:,1)), :);
```